# Why is a product collection using catalog_product_entity instead of catalog_product_flat_1 database table?

Tags: magento

I have a magento installation that is using `catalog_product_entity`, while others use `catalog_product_flat_1` during the query to retrieve a product collection.

Why is this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can configure if Magento uses flat table or entity for collections. Check `Use Flat Catalog Product` in Magento admin section under `System->Config->Catalog: Frontend`. When changing this setting flush Magento cache storage because admin configuration is cached. Index invalidation might also play a role here, I'm not sure if Magento uses flat tables when it's not up to date.

[Buttle Butkus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/631764/buttle-butkus) reported it might be necessary to switch it to `No` and back to `Yes` again to activate it.

If you are loading the collection in the admin area flat tables aren't used.

This is determined in `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection::_construct()`:

```
/**
 * Initialize resources
 *
 */
protected function _construct()
{
    if ($this->isEnabledFlat()) {
        $this->_init('catalog/product', 'catalog/product_flat');
    }
    else {
        $this->_init('catalog/product');
    }
    $this->_initTables();
}

/**
* Retrieve is flat enabled flag
* Return alvays false if magento run admin
*
* @return bool
*/
public function isEnabledFlat()
{
if (Mage::app()->getStore()->isAdmin()) {
    return false;
}
if (!isset($this->_flatEnabled[$this->getStoreId()])) {
    $this->_flatEnabled[$this->getStoreId()] = $this->getFlatHelper()
        ->isEnabled($this->getStoreId());
}
    return $this->_flatEnabled[$this->getStoreId()];
}
```

Comment: Are you sure about that? That was my first thought, but it seems like it is already selected in the backend. Is it possible to override the backend somewhere else? In an xml template file or in one of the php files?

Comment: Hi Simon. It turns out that, for some reason, the Admin can improperly reflect the actual backend settings. I was able to fix the problem by switching the admin settings to `No`, saving, then switching back to `Yes` and saving again. I'm going to edit your answer with that additional suggestion and if you accept that edit then you will surely receive my check mark.

Comment: Your edits were already reviewed so it wasn't possible to accept them. I added your results and a hint about caching.